# How to create an object of a generic class with multiple parameters

Tags: java

Now I have a class created as below :

```
class Test <T extends Number & List<String>>    
{
T i;
T k;
public void show(){
    System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

I want to create an object of Test class but I am getting error with all possible combinations. Below is the main class in which I am trying to create an object of Test class and failing horribly. Please help.

```
public class CollectionsDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<ArrayList<Integer>> t = new Test<ArrayList<Integer>>();

}       
}
```

Every time the compiler is throwing below error :

```
Bound mismatch: The type ArrayList<Integer> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Number & List<String>> of the type Test<T>
```

Comment: That's not multiple parameters. That's one parameter that's required to somehow be both a Number and a List of Strings, and the actual type you're passing in is neither. Could you clarify how this type is actually supposed to be used?

Comment: Besides, invoking a constructor is done using `new`.

Comment: I guess missed putting new while posting the question. Also going by your comment I tried making  "class Test <T extends Number & List<Number>>  ".  So in this case I should be able to create an object of Test with parameter "ArrayList<Integer>. Still facing the same issue. I just wanted to understand how this works when we are passing two types in generics.

Answer (score 1):

This class:

```
class Test <T extends Number & List<String>>
```

has only one type parameter: `T`. `Number` and `List<String>` are type bounds. In plain English this reads: class Test works for any type `T` which both extends `Number` and implements `List<String>`. `ArrayList<Integer>` is neither `List` of `Strings` nor a `Number`.

To instantiate `Test` you would need a class like:

```
class ListNumber extends Number implements List<String>
```

That's a strange class. It doesn't look like it really is what you want. Maybe you just want "List containing Numbers": `Test <List<T extends Number>>`? Or, "List and a Number": `Test <T extends List<String>, V extends Number>`.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Instead of standard ArrayList which does not satisfy my bound types creating a customized class fixes the issue.